# влияние display inline-flex на других элементов

Tags: flexbox

Как бы все работает нормом но появляется некий отступ на других элементов когда двай таких inline-flex контейнеры никаких проблем!

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


.flex-container{
  outline: 1px solid #f00;
 display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.boxes{
 outline: 1px solid #f00;
 background: #6AD0B5;

}


span{
 outline: 1px solid ;
 display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="boxes"> quam, sapiente dolorem, rem expedita, veniam dicta obcaecati sit, quod voluptatum ipsa iusto neque cupiditate iure reiciendis?</div>
    <div class="boxes"> quam, sapiente dolorem, rem expedita, veniam dicta obcaecati sit, quod voluptatum ipsa iusto neque cupiditate iure reiciendis?</div>
 </div>

 <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, dolorum!</span>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема, только оба соседствующих элемента были `inline-flex`. Так как элементы в том числе обладают инлайновыми свойствами, то мне помогло  `vertical-align: top` (достаточно добавить одному из элементов).
На твоем примере: https://codepen.io/diana_belka/pen/OJyOJBM
По дефолту стоит baseline, но я, честно говоря, не поняла еще, почему родительский элемент растягивается и смещается этот самый baseline.